# Liferay Error while starting bundle. (Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: )

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, build.gradle, liferay

My installed Tech and versions:
Liferay Developer Studio
Version: 3.9.0.202010130127-ga1
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 1.8.0_271
Server: Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.3.5 CE GA6 ; tomcat 9.0.37 at localhost
Node - v10.17.0
Npm - v6.11.3 (I have also tested this with the latest version of node & npm )
Gradle - v6.8-rc-1

For testing purposes, I've created a new *Liferay_Workspace* and *Test* module with a fresh installation of both the developer studio and server. The *build.gradle* and *bnd.bnd* files are left default with no changes made in them. By *clean* and *build* gradle tasks execute successfully with no errors. Upon deploying the built jar files in the deploy folder of the running tomcat server I observe the following errors.

> Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.liferay.frontend.js.loader.modules.extender.npm; version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"_ [Sanitized]

In the past, specifying various versions in the *build.gradle* file hasn't helped me solve this issue. This is also observed while trying to import other packages too.

**TLDR: I am trying to build and deploy a fresh and untouched module with no changes in it only to receive the above mentioned errors**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your workspace's `gradle.properties` (in root directory) contains the correct `liferay.workspace.target.platform.version` entry.

And, if you use the module's dependency declaration in `build.gradle`, that it matches the version you're compiling for:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.api", version: "7.3.5-ga6"
}
```

I'm not sure which of both has preference over the other, but I'm assuming it's the individual module that overrides the general workspace setting. But it can't hurt to have both in sync